# Comparison between Pandas dataframe column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a Pandas df that looks like this:

```
   Start    End
0  16360  16362
1  16367  16381
2  16374  16399
3  16401  16413
4  16417  16427
5  16428  16437
6  16435  16441
7  16442  16444
8  16457  16463
```

In this dataframe, all `'Start'` values of a certain row come after the `'End'` values of the row before (i.e., `row 1: 16367` > `row 0: 16362`), **but** this is *not true* for rows `2` and `6`.

I'd like to make a counter `i=0` which length increases for each time this "error" comes (in this case `i` becomes `i=2`). Something like:

```
for each Start value of my df:
    if the value is < than the End of the row before:
        i = i+1
```

How can I do this with Pandas?

Moreover, I want to make things harder: I'd like to add a `'Length'` column like this:

```
mydf['Length'] = mydf['End'] - mydf['Start']
```

To obtain something like this:

```
   Start    End    Length
0  16360  16362    2
1  16367  16381    4
2  16374  16399    25
3  16401  16413    12
4  16417  16427    10
5  16428  16437    9
6  16435  16441    6
7  16442  16444    2
8  16457  16463    6
```

Again, for rows `2` and `6` I have the previously described problem. When this problem comes, I'd like to have the  `'Length'`  column that is not given by  `'End'`  -  `'Start'`  anymore but is the result of  `'End' (i.e., of row 6)` -  `'End' (of row 5)`.

In pseudocode could look like this:

```
for each Start value of my df:
    if the value is < than the End of the row before:
        mydf['Length'] = mydf['End'] of the actual row - mydf['End'] of the row before
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
# is the previous End > to the current Start?
m = df['End'].shift().gt(df['Start'])
# propagate error count
df['Error'] = m.cumsum()
# Length = End - Start if no error, else End - previous End
df['Length'] = df['End'].sub(df['Start'].mask(m, df['End'].shift()))
```

output:

```
   Start    End  Error  Length
0  16360  16362      0     2.0
1  16367  16381      0    14.0
2  16374  16399      1    18.0
3  16401  16413      1    12.0
4  16417  16427      1    10.0
5  16428  16437      1     9.0
6  16435  16441      2     4.0
7  16442  16444      2     2.0
8  16457  16463      2     6.0
```

Comment: Wow ok than you so much mozway!

Comment: You're welcome @Iacopo I added a minor improvement

Answer (score 1):

the alternative approach could be:

```
err = (df.End.shift()-df.Start).mask(lambda x: x<0, pd.NA)
i = err.count()

df['length'] = df.End - df.Start - err.fillna(0)

print(f'{i = }')
print(df)
'''
i = 2
   Start    End  length
0  16360  16362     2.0
1  16367  16381    14.0
2  16374  16399    18.0
3  16401  16413    12.0
4  16417  16427    10.0
5  16428  16437     9.0
6  16435  16441     4.0
7  16442  16444     2.0
8  16457  16463     6.0
```

for better visualization you can add "err" column:

```
df['err'] = err
print(df)
'''
   Start    End  length  err
0  16360  16362     2.0  NaN
1  16367  16381    14.0  NaN
2  16374  16399    18.0  7.0
3  16401  16413    12.0  NaN
4  16417  16427    10.0  NaN
5  16428  16437     9.0  NaN
6  16435  16441     4.0  2.0
7  16442  16444     2.0  NaN
8  16457  16463     6.0  NaN
```